# Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists with Zend_Form_Element_File

Tags: zend-framework

Is it possible to assign the Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists validator to a Zend_Form_Element_File? Here's how I am trying to do this:

```
$file = new Zend_Form_Element_File('datei');
$file->setLabel('Datei (maximal 2 MB)')
     ->addValidator('Count', false, 1)
     ->addValidator('Size', false, 2048000)
     ->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpg,gif,jpeg,pdf')
     ->addValidator('Db_NoRecordExists', false, array(
         'table'   => 'presseservice_pm_upload',
         'field'   => 'datei',
     ))
     ->setRequired(true);
```

However it doesn't seem to work when I upload a file with the same name as one already stored in presseservice_pm_upload.datei field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Zend_Form_Element_File` does not use the standard `Zend_Validate` validators. It uses the file validators from [`Zend_File_Transfer`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.file.transfer.validators.html).

It's likely you'll have to do some code gymnastics to get this to validate against a database.

Good Luck!

Comment: I started already to implement the check with separate validator, but actually "NotExists" is what I need - in my case it is even better than validating against database - thank you for this hint ;)